# Laravel - using subdomain as staging environment when using socialite

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've a domain says www.example.com and created a staging environment from it says stag.example.com.

In my server i then cloned my file to two different folder example and stag.example folders. Each of them have the .env file set correctly.

My problem i've faced is when i visit www.example.com, it generate a laravel_session with the name of .example.com and i'm able to login with facebook. With the dot infront, laravel session is able to share across the sub domain.

Now if i go to stag.example.com and login with facebook, it seems like it will go look for the laravel session with the name of .example.com instead of the session generated by the apps itself, Therefore when i login with facebook, i will get InvalidStateException at AbstractProvider.php line 191.

I can access to stag.example.com and login with facebook only when i removed the .example.com laravel session.

am i doing the wrong way to setup the staging environment using subdomain? 
Or we shouldnt use sub domain as staging environment?

Below are the .env file for production

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=**Secrect**
APP_DOMAIN=example.com

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=example
DB_USERNAME=**Secrect**
DB_PASSWORD=**Secrect**

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

SESSION_DOMAIN=example.com

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

S3_KEY=**Secrect**
S3_SECRET=**Secrect**
S3_BUCKET=**Secrect**

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=**Secrect**
MAILGUN_SECRET=**Secrect**

FB_CLIENT_ID=**Secrect**
FB_CLIENT_SECRET=**Secrect**
FB_REDIRECT=http://example.com/login/facebookCallback
```

In staging

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=**Secrect**
APP_DOMAIN=example.com

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=example
DB_USERNAME=**Secrect**
DB_PASSWORD=**Secrect**

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

SESSION_DOMAIN=stag.example.com

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

S3_KEY=**Secrect**
S3_SECRET=**Secrect**
S3_BUCKET=**Secrect**

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=**Secrect**
MAILGUN_SECRET=**Secrect**

FB_CLIENT_ID=**Secrect**
FB_CLIENT_SECRET=**Secrect**
FB_REDIRECT=http://stag.example.com/login/facebookCallback
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Laravel expects you to link to the same project when using subdomains with sessions.

There are several solutions for this. 
For example one is using another session driver that can be shared between projects.

Another is to use another cookie name in both projects. You can change the cookie name in `config\session.php`. You can add an `getenv()` function here so you can set the cookie name in you `.env` file.

Comment: can i set the cookie name like this ?
'cookie' => 'stag.example',

Comment: Indeed, but I would use an enviroment variable so you don't accidentaly change the cookie name on your live server.

Comment: But once i've chaneg the cookie name to stag.example.
When i do a form post, it gives me TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Comment: That has nothing to do with this. But you should remove all cookies from your browser for this page and reload the page before trying again.

Comment: Im able to do form post when i clear the cookies, but once i visit www.example.com and try to do a form post in stag.example.com, it gives me TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53

Comment: So, you do a post from your live to your staging server? This is impossible when using csrf with different sessions.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstand. What i means what when i visit to my live server www.example.com, it generate laravel_session .example.com. Then i go back to staging server and do a post form, it gives me tokenmistachexception.

It's working fine when i clear out all the cookie, and it's able to do a form post before i visit to www.example.com. after i've visit www.example.com. i will get tokenmistachexception in staging server.

Comment: So what you means is i need to set two different cookie name in both different project?
becoz right now i only set the cookie name in staging.